# URL Rewriting with two URL parameters

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am attempting URL Rewriting for a URL with two get parameters, I want to covert a page:

```
status/mystatus.php?=reference=1234&postcode=LL1+LL2
```

Into:

```
status/1234/LL1+LL2
```

I have tried using the following code:

```
RewriteRule ^status/([a-z0-9A-Z]+)/([a-z0-9A-Z]+)$ status/mystatus.php?reference=$1&postcode=$2 [NC,L]
```

But it doesn't seem to be working, so what am I doing wrong?
(The module is turned on, I am using Apache)

Comment: after you "turned on the module", have you restart Apache ?

Comment: It's not really under my control, but I know it works because it is working with a different url like I can send requests for details to details.php

Comment: as @ShivanRaptor mentioned ensure `RewriteEngine On` is at the top of your .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the expressions inside the parentheses to `[^/]+` so it looks like:

```
RewriteRule ^status/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ status/mystatus.php?reference=$1&postcode=$2 [NC,L]
```

Because `[a-z0-9A-Z]` won't match things like "+".

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^status/(.*)/(.*)+(.*)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me by answering my question. I am voting for you. It's the most I can do here for you :-)